# is it possible to send the $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER] when doing a header(location: ) request?

Tags: php, iphone, web-applications, redirect

I want to create a redirect page with the HTTP_REFERER of the previous page which was just a redirect page:

let's say I have home.php, in there you click on a link, you get to redirect.php which is just a `location("finish.php");` And I need to get the referer adress of redirect.php, but it gives me only the home.php referer.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
This is for iPhone webapp transition from full screen mode to browser mode if that helps anyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have absolutely no influence over the HTTP Referer header that **the client** sends to the server. You cannot instruct the client to send a specific header on its next request, because it's none of the server's business (so to speak).

Transport the information in the URL as query variable or via cookies/sessions instead. You should do this anyway, since the Referer header is purely optional and informational and should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't - you can't change the clients/browsers way of sending those headers.

Use sessions as a solution for your redirection instead - that would also provide you with some flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible.you can't trust to HTTP_REFERER but you can save current $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to the session and use this to redirect